# finding index of key in an ordered dictionary in powershell

Tags: powershell, dictionary, indexing, hashtable, indexof

I am having a little bit of trouble with hashtables/dictionaries in powershell.  The most recent roadblock is the ability to find the index of a key in an ordered dictionary.

- **I am looking for a solution that isn't simply iterating through the object.**
  (*I already know how to do that*)

Consider the following example:

```
$dictionary = [Ordered]@{
    'a' = 'blue';
    'b'='green';
    'c'='red'
    }
```

If this were a normal array I'd be able to look up the index of an entry by using IndexOf().

```
[array]::IndexOf($dictionary,'c').
```

That would return 2 under normal circumstances.

If I try that with an ordered dictionary, though, I get -1.

Any solutions?

---

***Edit:***
In case anyone reading over this is wondering what I'm talking about.  What I was trying to use this for was to create an object to normalize property entries in a way that also has a numerical order.

I was trying to use this for the status of a process, for example:

```
$_processState = [Ordered]@{
     'error' = 'error'
     'none' = 'none'
     'started' = 'started'
     'paused' = 'paused'
     'cleanup' = 'cleanup'
     'complete' = 'complete'
}
```

If you were able to easily do this, the above object would give `$_processState.error` an index value of 0 and ascend through each entry, finally giving `$_processState.complete` an index value of 5.  Then if you compared two properties, by "index value", you could see which one is further along by simple operators.  For instance:

```
$thisObject.Status = $_processState.complete
If ($thisObject.Status -ge $_processState.cleanup) {Write-Host 'All done!'}

PS > All done!
```

^^that doesn't work as is, but that's the idea.  It's what I was aiming for.  Or maybe to find something like $_processState.complete.IndexNumber()

Having an object like this also lets you assign values by the index name, itself, while standardizing the options...

```
$thisObject.Status = $_processState.paused
$thisObject.Status

PS > paused
```

Not really sure this was the best approach at the time or if it still is the best approach with all the custom class options there are available in PS v5.

Comment: added edit to clarify what I was talking about because coming back to the question left me confused at first.

Comment: I added a solution using Enums which is new as of PS v5.  That is essentially what I was trying to replicate with my problem, and since they added in enums, I no longer need a work around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It can be simpler

It may not be any more efficient than the answer from Frode F., but perhaps more concise (inline) would be simply putting the hash table's `keys` collection in a sub expression (`$()`) then calling indexOf on the result.

### For your hash table...

Your particular expression would be simply:

```
$($dictionary.keys).indexOf('c')
```

...which gives the value `2` as you expected. This also works just as well on a regular hashtable... unless the hashtable is modified in pretty much any way, of course... so it's probably not very useful in that case.

### In other words

Using this hash table (which also shows many of the ways to encode `4`...):

```
$hashtable = [ordered]@{
    sample = 'hash table'
    0 = 'hello'
    1 = 'goodbye'
    [char]'4' = 'the ansi character 4 (code 52)'
    [char]4 = 'the ansi character code 4'
    [int]4 = 'the integer 4'
    '4' = 'a string containing only the character 4'
    5 = "nothing of importance"
}
```

would yield the following expression/results pairs:

```
# Expression                                 Result
#-------------------------------------      -------------
$($hashtable.keys).indexof('5')              -1
$($hashtable.keys).indexof(5)                 7
$($hashtable.keys).indexof('4')               6
$($hashtable.keys).indexof([char]4)           4
$($hashtable.keys).indexof([int]4)            5
$($hashtable.keys).indexof([char]'4')         3
$($hashtable.keys).indexof([int][char]'4')   -1
$($hashtable.keys).indexof('sample')          0
```

by the way:

- `[int][char]'4'` equals `[int]52`
- `[char]'4'` has a "value" (magnitude?) of `52`, but is a character, so it's used as such

...gotta love the typing system, which, while flexible, can get really really bad at times, if you're not careful.

Comment: I think this is about as close to what I was getting at as I was able to find.

Comment: This doesn't work if you start out with an empty ordered dictionary. `$(([ordered]@{}).Keys).IndexOf` returns `$null` and `$(([ordered]@{'asdf'='asdf'}).Keys).IndexOf('asd')` returns `0` instead of `-1`.

Comment: I found an alternate solution; instead of `$($hashtable.Keys).IndexOf`, use `([array]$hashtable.Keys).IndexOf`. This will convert keys from `OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection` to an array instead of an arbitrary type.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries uses keys and not indexes. OrderedDictionary combines a `hashtable` and `ArrayList` to give you order/index-support in a dictionary, however it's still a dictionary (key-based) collection.

If you need to get the index of an object in a `OrderedDictionary` (or a `hasthable`) you need to use foreach-loop and a counter. Example (should be created as a function):

```
$hashTable = [Ordered]@{
    'a' = 'blue';
    'b'='green';
    'c'='red'
}

$i = 0
foreach($key in $hashTable.Keys) {
    if($key -eq "c") { $i; break }
    else { $i++ }
}
```

That's how it works internaly too. You can verify this by reading the source code for `OrderedDictionary`'s `IndexOfKey` method in [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Comment: you can address the ordered dictionary by index number.  so $hashTable[2] returns "red".

as to _why_ I would want to do that, I don't think it's relevant.  I'm trying to understand how this works and find a solution to the problem I have, then share that solution for others who might hit the same roadblocks.

like I said in the question, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve iterating through the object.

Comment: I was hoping there was some sort of method or a way to modify the dictionary without having to run through an iteration loop.  I'll just stick to that then, thanks for the explanation & answer!

Answer (score 1):

For the initial problem I was attempting to solve, a comparable process state, you can now use Enumerations starting with PowerShell v5.

You use the Enum keyword, set the Enumerators by name, and give them an integer value.  The value can be anything, but I'm using ascending values starting with 0 in this example:

```
Enum _ProcessState{
    Error = 0
    None = 1
    Started = 2
    Paused = 3
    Cleanup = 4
    Complete = 5
    Verified = 6
}

#the leading _ for the Enum is just cosmetic & not required
```

Once you've created the Enum, you can assign it to variables.  The contents of the variable will return the text name of the Enum, and you can compare them as if they were integers.

```
$Item1_State = [_ProcessState]::Started
$Item2_State = [_ProcessState]::Cleanup

#return state of second variable
$Item2_state

#comparison
$Item1_State -gt $Item2_State
```

*Will return:*

```
Cleanup
False
```

If you wanted to compare and return the highest:

```
#sort the two objects, then return the first result (should return the item with the largest enum int)
$results = ($Item1_State,$Item2_State | Sort-Object -Descending)
$results[0]
```

Fun fact, you can also use arithmetic on them, for example:

```
$Item1_State + 1
$Item1_State + $Item2_State
```

*Will return:*

```
Paused
Verified
```

More info on Enum here:

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/08/26/new-powershell-5-feature-enumerations/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum?view=powershell-6
- https://psdevopsug.scot/post/working-with-enums-in-powershell/